# vimperator: write foo.html without foo_files/*

Tags: firefox, vimperator

When saving a webpage with `:w foo.html`, vimperator also creates a directory `foo_files`, whose contents I find to be bloaty and uninteresting.  How can I tell vimperator to behave like Firefox's file / save page as / **web page html only**, instead of file / save page as / **web page complete**?

(Its own documentation `liberator://help/browsing#writing` mentions no options.)

Comment: Not sure how to change that behaviour of `:w`, but there is a keyboard only solution which is `i CTRL-S` which pops a modal for saving the page via Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A keyboard only workaround, which doesn't use Vimperator, is to pop Firefox's Save As modal and pick "web page only" as you mention.

Use: `i <C-S>`

Explanation: `i` sets Vimperator to ignore the next key press. Then `<C-S>` ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) reaches Firefox and triggers "Save Page As" behaviour.